# Run the same task with different parameters and dynamic dependencies with Luigi

Tags: pipeline, luigi

I think this is a common thing and I'm just struggling to figure out the proper luigi dependency structure, but here is the case:

I have a folder full of csv files.
TaskA makes pairs out of the csv files, and writes the paths of the paired files to a .txt file

TaskB should take a pair of paths, and do something with the 2 csv files the paths target

TaskC should take the output of TaskA, and schedule N TaskBs, once for each pair in TaskA's output.

Roughly the code would look like this:

```
class TaskA(luigi.Task):
    data_dir = luigi.Parameter()

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('list_of_pairs.txt')

    def run(self):
        files = os.listdir(self.data_dir)
        pairs = MakePairs(files)
        with self.output().open('w') as fout:
            for x, y in pairs:
                 fout.write('{},{}\n'.format(x, y))

class TaskB(luigi.Task):
    file1 = luigi.Parameter()
    file2 = luigi.Parameter()

    def run(self):
        with open(self.file1, 'r') as f1, open(self.file2, 'r') as f2, self.output().open('w') as fout:
            newdata = DoSomething()
            fout.write(newdata)

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget(os.path.join(target_dir, self.file1[:-3] + '.foo'))


class TaskC(luigi.Task):
    work_dir = luigi.Parameter()

    def requires(self):
        return TaskA(self.work_dir)

    def run(self):
        task_b_list = []
        with self.input().open('r') as fin:
            for line in fin:
                file1, file2 = line.split(',')
                task_b_list.append(TaskB(file1, file2))
        yield task_b_list
        DoStuff()

def output(self):
    return luigi.LocalTarget('output_c')
```

Am I doing this right? Or is there some other way to do this? The reason I'm doing it this way is want to allow multiple workers to do the work done in task B because the files are large, which is why taskC is sort of just a scheduler for taskB

Comment: Small adding question. is it possible to configure different parameters in **one** config file for **one** task?